# Changing Gmail reply tag from "Re" to "RE"

Tags: gmail

When I reply to a message having subject line, let's say `Welcome`, then the subject line becomes `Re:Welcome`. I want it to be `RE:Welcome`. I want `RE` instead of `Re`. Of course, I can edit it while replying. But is there any setting I can make so that whenever I reply, the subject line automatically has `RE` instead of `Re`?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid no, there is no setting in Gmail to change the reply indicator from "Re:" to "RE:".